# Homomorphisms induced by maps $S^1 \times S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Problem 2.2.30 in Hatcher involves the homomorphisms $H_2(S^1\times S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow H_2(S^1\times S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ induced by

> The map $S^1 \times S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ that is the identity on one factor and a reflection on the other.

and

> The map $S^1 \times S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \times S^1$ that interchanges the two factors and then reflects one of the factors.

I strongly suspect that the induced homomorphisms are $-\mathbf{1}$ and $\mathbf{1}$, respectively. How would I prove this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Künneth formula?

Comment: I want to avoid it because Hatcher does not mention the formula until Chapter 3.

Comment: Would simplicial homology work? It seems concrete enough that you could directly compute it.

Comment: Simplicial homology would work, and so would cellular homology. Find the generator(s) of each homology group and see what $f$ maps them to.

Comment: I tried to use the $\Delta$-complex structure on page 102 of Hatcher in which a square is divided into two triangles across a diagonal. Then $H_2$ is generated by $U-L$, where $U$ and $L$ are the upper and lower triangles. Switching the factors interchanges $L$ and $U$ because it reflects the square across the diagonal. I think that the map reflecting one factor corresponds to either a horizontal or vertical reflection, but both of these reflections result in a square with the diagonal going the other way.

Comment: Yes, that is annoying, but you can take a $\Delta$-complex structure that is preserved under switching factors and reflection. For example, you can draw both diagonals, so you have 4 triangles instead of 2.